# How would one set up barycentric coordinates for a trapezoid?

Tags: quadrilateral, barycentric-coordinates

Barycentric coordinates are great for triangles, but I'm interested in how to construct a barycentric coordinate system for an arbitrary trapezoid.

I've seen this done for an arbitrary quadrilateral, but it ought to be simpler in the case of a trapezoid because of the two parallel sides. There does not appear to be information on this specific case online.

[This source](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/cdbb/5aa0b2ad612182dc9a75178082bb1804750a.pdf) has a good solution in general, but has this note: "Note that the special case $\vec{c}\times\vec{d}=0$ must be treated separately", but gives no explanation of how the special case must be treated. This special case turns out to be when two opposite sides are parallel — the definition of a trapezoid.

Comment: By using the term barycenter, are you finding the center of mass if unequal weights are attached to the vertices?

Comment: I know that's where the term originated, but it seems to have gone beyond that use, though I'm not sure how. My application is to interpolate values on a trapezoid. Similar, but slightly different!

Answer (score 0):

The source derives that

$$(\mathbf{c} \times \mathbf{d})\mu^2 + (\mathbf{c} \times \mathbf{b} + \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{d})\mu + \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} = 0.$$

When $\mathbf{c} \times \mathbf{d}$ is zero, we should just be able to conclude that

$$\mu = \frac{\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}}{\mathbf{c} \times \mathbf{b} + \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{d}}.$$

I think perhaps they mean that one cannot apply the quadratic formula in this case.